# In WinRT, how do I get the parent of a button in a listviewitem?

Tags: windows-runtime

I'd like to get the ListViewItem of a button.  In normal WPF, I'd use GetContainerForItem() but can't find the equivalent for WinRT.  In my AddButton_Click() function, you will see the brittle way that I get the id of the item that the associated button was pushed.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Custom80ItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="6">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="40" Height="40" Click="AddButton_Click" Content="&#xE118;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Style="{StaticResource TextButtonStyle}" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" MaxHeight="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding group}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>


    <ListView x:Name="searchResultsListView" Grid.Row="1"
              SelectionMode="None" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="10,0,10,10" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Custom80ItemTemplate}" />

    private async void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent1 = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Parent;
        var grid = parent1 as Grid;
        var stackpanel = grid.Children[1] as StackPanel;
        var textBlock = stackpanel.Children[1] as TextBlock;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to access the elements in the template directly? If you only want to access `id` value of the clicked item, you could just put the command for the button in the item itself:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }

    public ICommand command { get; set; }

    public ItemViewModel
    {
        command = new RelayCommand(_ => OnClick());
    }

    private void OnClick()
    {
        // access id here
    }
}
```

You can find a `RelayCommand` implementation [here](http://relaycommandrt.codeplex.com/).

Now just replace the event handler by binding `command`:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Width="40" Height="40" Command="{Binding command}" Content="&#xE118;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Style="{StaticResource TextButtonStyle}" />
```

Comment: Wow, that was super obvious.  :)  This is the answer I was looking for.